# No Screen with name "new_screen"

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm having a problem that is upon pressing the get random color screen, it should add a screen widget and switch to the screen with name "new_screen". Instead it gives me an error saying there's no screen with name "new_screen.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
import time
import random

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ColourScreen(Screen):
    colour = ListProperty([1., 0., 0., 1.])

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def new_colour_screen(self):
        self.add_widget(ColourScreen(name="new_screen",colour=[random.random() for _ in range(3)] + [1]))
        self.current = "new_screen"

root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

MyScreenManager:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    FirstScreen:
    SecondScreen:

<FirstScreen>:
    name: 'first'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'first screen!'
            font_size: 30
        Image:
            source: 'colours.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'goto second screen'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.current = 'second'
            Button:
                text: 'get random colour screen'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.new_colour_screen()

<SecondScreen>:
    name: 'second'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'second screen!'
            font_size: 30
        Image:
            source: 'colours2.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'goto first screen'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.current = 'first'
            Button:
                text: 'get random colour screen'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.new_colour_screen()

<ColourScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'colour {:.2},{:.2},{:.2} screen'.format(*root.colour[:3])
            font_size: 30
        Widget:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: root.colour
                Ellipse:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'goto first screen'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.current = 'first'
            Button:
                text: 'get random colour screen'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.new_colour_screen()

''')

class ScreenManagerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root_widget

ScreenManagerApp().run()
```

Comment: Seems to work for me. Note that if you click on your `get random colour screen` button more than once, you will be creating multiple `ColourScreens` with the same `name`. Not a good idea.

Comment: How come it’s still giving me an error >< is there anything I should check on ?

Comment: Strange. Try replacing the contents of your `new_colour_screen()` method with just the one line: `self.switch_to(ColourScreen(name="new_screen",colour=[random.random() for _ in range(3)] + [1]))`.

Comment: It works, thanks again